# Store logs from appservice to Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have some errors in Application Insights when try storing logs to Application Insights

```
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. 
Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights' will not be create. 
Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. 
Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IApplicationIdProvider'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights' will not be create.
Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. 
Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
```

I enabled Application Insights

The image of logs in appinsight
[image]

The image activities logs when enable appinsights
[image]

***Appsettings***
**[image: Appsettings]**

[The older logs in Transaction Search of Application Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM27p.png)

[The newest logs in Transaction Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K7RN.png)

[Only trace logs have problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoTgJ.png)

Comment: Can you please share the code and how you have configured Application Insights

Comment: If possible try to share your code repo.

Comment: I only config appinsights in portal.azure. Do I need to config it in my code ?

Comment: Step 1: Enable AppInsights 
Step 2: In category Instrument your application, I choose the .NET

Comment: What is the version of your App?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8.1

Comment: Do you have any web app code in local?

Comment: Firts line of error clearly says to configure ApplicationInsights from code.

Comment: Make sure your InstrumentationKey is Correct

Comment: Iam not getting any errors,Even I have configured it from Portal.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/9c64mOl.png)

Comment: I have some confuse about settings between portal.azure and file config in code. 
1. Could we need to config only portal.azure, not config in code? 
2. If we config both in portal.azure and code local, when we build the code in appservice. Do appinsights    Prioritize the config value in portal? 
Thanks so much

Comment: You can do in both the ways.I suggest you to configure from code for getting in detailed traces.

Comment: Can you please share the environment variables appsettings screen shot of your Azure web app

Comment: I have just sent the image of Appsettings. You can find it in my question at  The image of Appsettings

Comment: Will check and let you know

Comment: I have just post new image. I see some logs in transaction search. But they are not all logs and they can't be showed in Logs (at left panel of Application Insights)

Comment: Check Transaction Search option in Application Insights once.

Comment: Yes, I have just post new image

Comment: You are getting logs rights.Hope your issue is resolved now

Comment: Yes I have just post the newest logs

Comment: Let me know If you are looking for anything else

Comment: I have just add new image of transaction search. It seems only trace logs have problem.

Comment: To log traces you need to configure it in Code.

Comment: Can you explain me clearly because I'm a new commer in this field. The difference between transaction search and Logs azure. And how I config them (in code or in azure portal)

Comment: First let me know what you want to see in trace logs.

Comment: I want to see the debug logger, the request, exception, the infomation logs.

Comment: Do I need to config in code if I want to see the logs in LOGS (at the left panel in Applications Insights)

Comment: No....it is not required

Comment: I have _logger.Debug(message); in my local code. I use the log4net framework. How I can show it in LOGS (at the left panel in Applications Insights)?

Comment: Please share your log4net  configuration and local code

Answer (score 0):

```
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. 
Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights' will not be create. 
Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. 
Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IApplicationIdProvider'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights' will not be create.
Error: 'Constructor on type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor' not found.'. Monitoring will continue if you set InstrumentationKey programmatically.
AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. 
Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
does not implement 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryInitializer'. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.
```

I think it is fine if I add some nugetpackages bellow in my code and this error doesn'n affect the logs in application insights
[Nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zinJe.png)

Comment: That's the reason I asked you to configure from code